# How to use more efficient get and set

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign values and it works, but I want to write it with less code.

```
public decimal StudentValue
{
    get
    {
        return _studentValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _studentValue = value;
        subTotal.Text = _studentValue.ToString();
    }
}
public decimal VATValue
{
    get
    {
        return _teacherValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _teacherValue = value;
        total.Text = _teacherValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use databinding instead of directly assigning a value to textbox. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As the code is common - use a method to set the value & the label(?) text. Other than that, how are you expecting to make the code more efficient?

Comment: Why do you have a property on a class that appears to be updating a UI control's value?

Answer (score 1):

Set the assign into a function
insert:

```
if (vAT.Text == "0,00" || vAT.Text == null)
{
    vAT.Text = _VATValue.ToString();
}
```

into a function like this:

```
private void Assigning(ref string txt, string val)
{

    if (txt == "0,00" || txt == null)
    {
         txt = val;
    }
}
```

and call this funciton:
Assigning(ref vAT.Text, value.ToString());

hope it helps